# What classes needs to be used to get daily reminders at exact time in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, reminders

I have tried the Alarm manager class with setRepeating method to achieve the daily reminders. But it works properly only on stock android devices. Most of the Chinese devices failed to receive the reminders.

Most of them recommending to use "Evernote android-job" library. But it's is deprecated and they are mentioned that to use WorkManager.

Work Manager is not suitable for exact timing operations.

Please help me to achieve the daily reminders.

Answer (score 0):

Try Firebase jobdispatcher github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

```
 FirebaseJobDispatcher jobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(
                    new GooglePlayDriver(mContext));



  Job networkJob = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                            .setService(MyJobService.class)
                            .setTag(notificationTime)
                            .setRecurring(true)
                            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(startSeconds, startSeconds + 1))
                            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK, Constraint.DEVICE_IDLE)
                            .build();

                    jobDispatcher.mustSchedule(networkJob);
                    int resultCodeStatus = jobDispatcher.schedule(networkJob);

                    if (resultCodeStatus != FirebaseJobDispatcher.SCHEDULE_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                        Log.d("JOB_TAG", "Job ERROR ON SCHEDULE");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("JOB_TAG", "Job scheduled");
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. But Firebase Job Dispatcher also deprecated they are also mentioned to use WorkManager. For reference, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Answer (score 0):

If you really need exact time, maybe it would be better to send a message from Firebase Messaging (at the exact time) using CRON job for example.

In the app you need to extend `FirebaseMessagingService()` and call the method to trigger reminder in `onMessageReceived` (you can send some data down along as well).

This approach is gonna work on all devices, and is resistant to app updates, OS updates and phone restarts.

Comment: Thanks freak for the reply. But i want to run the job also in without internet connection